# Unable to access internet when setting up Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4) step by step and I have to update and download this and that. The thing is, I can't access the internet on that machine (I used to can before messing up the settings). Any ideas? I tried going to `network` but I couldn't, nothing happens. Then I tried to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` back to dhcp but still no luck. Any ideas? 
It worths mentioning that I didn't follow blindly when setting the IP address, I checked mine using `ifconfig -a` and set the data from there. 
Update: I added a connection so now I can edit it but still no internet.

Comment: May we have a look? `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: sod it, I reinstalled the whole thing and it works. not sure why though.

Comment: We are glad it's working in any event!